# newline character display as space in sql server

Tags: sql-server, newline

I have table with a field of type varchar. I entered data to that field with a new line character. When i select i am not seeing newline.I am seeing space there. But for my friend i could see new line. Please help me find a solution to make it consistent.

> entered data  -

```
abc

abc1

abc2
```

> my output

```
abc abc1 abc2
```

> friends output

```
abc

abc1

abc2
```

can anybody tell me what can be the reason

Comment: What are you and your friend using to execute your query?

Comment: we are using ssms

Comment: Can you provide the query you are using ?

Comment: The newline will appear like a space when you have the output going to grid. But when the output is set to text it will have line breaks in the output.

Comment: is there anyway to display with line something like decoding @SeanLange

Comment: Is you friend getting his results in Grid or Text mode? Try hitting Ctrl+T or doing Query --> Results To ---> Results to Text and run your query again and I think it'll come out like his.

Comment: Huh? Look at the query results in SSMS. Those options are defaulted in the same toolbar as Execute and are on the far right end.

Comment: @Sean Lange - yes, but you can never know if he's changed his toolbar or moved them around so I was giving more sure fire ways to change the result style.  Myself I use the button as you say though :)

Comment: @ElementZero right....exactly why I said defaulted. I don't remember those shortcuts and don't have sql server open currently so just went from memory. :D

Comment: its for a report. in production user reported one issue saying there are not getting the newline in report. is there anyway in selection to show newline?